# Flutter, Text, not to break new line?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
RichText(
        text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(
            text: "aa a aa    ".replaceAll(' ', '\u00A0'),
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16,
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
          TextSpan(
            text: "   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb".replaceAll(' ', '\u00A0'),
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16,
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      )
```

When there was only one text, it was solved by just adding `.replaceAll('','\u00A0')`.

But in multiple text situations like richtext, how can you prevent new lines?

Flutter automatically creates a new line when the next text widget does not fit in one line.

I want `bbbbb...` to appear right next to `aaaaa`, not `bbbbb...` with a new line after `aaaaa`.

I expect

```
aaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

but it shows

```
aaaaa

bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

-- EDIT --

The code above works but only in English

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and got this response aaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb is this what you expect?

Comment: @DNS oh no why did you delete your answers? that answer had a lot of comments

Answer (score 0):

**I copied your code and it works perfectly fine it shows output of**

> aa a aa   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

**in a single line. Is this what you wanted ?**

```
RichText(
        text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(
            text: "aa a aa    ".replaceAll(' ', '\u00A0'),
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16,
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
          TextSpan(
            text: "   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb".replaceAll(' ', '\u00A0'),
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16,
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      )
```