# Flutter, how to make UI like "Youtube Live Chat"

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[image]

ID appears first, followed by a message. The important point is that the beginning of the second line is the place in the horizontal part starting from the first line ID.

What would you do if you were to implement it exactly the same way?

It doesn't seem to be possible with the Flexible Text Widget in the Row().

I would be appreciate for answer thanks

Comment: Try RichText for adjoining multiple text widgets.

Comment: @Sahdeep Singh I already tried that that doesn`t work. the Flutter automatically makes new line if next text widget is too long for one line

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[ListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html)** it comes with various paremeters

For example: According to your Screenshot sample code would be

```
ListTile(
    leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(userDisplayImage),
          //userDisplayImage would be URL
        ),
    title: Text(chatMessage),//Your Chat Message 
    trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
    //If you want to add functionality (eg. option) you can simply replace with
    trailin: IconButton(
          onPressed: () => print("Option"),//Add functionality
          icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
        ),
  );
```

I Hope this will resolve your issue

Comment: thanks but I think you have misunderstood. I actually don`t need to implement photo. I need "two texts widgets". and "The important point is that the beginning of the second line is the place in the horizontal part starting from the first line ID."

Comment: If you want to add two texts you can add "subtitle". So you can add two text in single ListTile . Let me know if I got your point

Comment: if you add "subtitle" you can see the subtitle is under the "title". I want it to be same line dude. I only want it to be next line "when the first line" is fulled

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `RichText` widget

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  width: 200,
  color: Colors.black,
  child: RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
      text: 'aaaaaa',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
      children: <TextSpan>[
        TextSpan(
          text: ' bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Obviously, you could pass two Strings to the two `TextSpan` widgets using two variables.
This is the output you get

[image]

Comment: No it doesn`t work replace Username with "aaaa" and others with "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb" then you can see bbbb is on the second line

Comment: I've just tried and it seems to work. Check the updated answer. Maybe you have bbb on the second line because the string is too long to fit on the first line after aaa, but it's short enough to fit on a new one by itself. I hope that makes sense. Try using actual words with spaces between them and you should be fine.

Comment: did you really get that output result? (EDITED ANSWER)  when I do that it is same could you see this example too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66621713/flutter-text-not-to-break-new-line/66624913#66624913

Comment: I don`t really get that output dude I did copy and paste

Comment: as I said, "bbbb..." appears from 2nd line.

Comment: Have you tried using actual words instead of a single long string of 'bbbbb'? That should work...